# reset a drop down list value to previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using javascript to validate some drop down list selections. One selection is for the length of a buildings frame. The other 3 drop down are for garage doors that can be added to the side. I have the code alerting me if the total door widths have exceeded the frame length. I need the if condition to take the previous value of the last selected door drop down list and reset it to the amount before it if the amount exceeds my conditions in my if statement.

This is my html

```
Frame Length:
<select id="framewidth" onchange="doorsrightsideFunction()">
    <option value="20">21</option>
    <option value="25">26</option>
    <option value="30">31</option>
    <option value="35">36</option>
    <option value="40">41</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="eight_by_seven_width_right_side" 
       id="eight_by_seven_width_right_side" value="8">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="eight_by_seven_height_right_side" 
       id="eight_by_seven_height_right_side" value="7">
<br>8x7:
<select id="eight_by_seven_right_side" onchange="doorsrightsideFunction()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="nine_by_seven_width_right_side" 
       id="nine_by_seven_width_right_side" value="9">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="nine_by_seven_height_right_side" 
       id="nine_by_seven_height_right_side" value="7">
<br>9x7:
<select id="nine_by_seven_right_side" onchange="doorsrightsideFunction()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="ten_by_eight_width_right_side" 
       id="ten_by_eight_width_right_side" value="10">
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="ten_by_eight_height_right_side" 
       id="ten_by_eight_height_right_side" value="8">
<br>10x8:
<select id="ten_by_eight_right_side" onchange="doorsrightsideFunction()">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

This is my javascript so far

```
function doorsrightsideFunction() {

    function getValue(idElement) {
        return document.getElementById(idElement).value;
    }    
    var eightwidth = getValue("eight_by_seven_width_right_side");
    var ninewidth = getValue("nine_by_seven_width_right_side");
    var tenwidth = getValue("ten_by_eight_width_right_side");
    var eightwidthamount = getValue("eight_by_seven_right_side");
    var ninewidthamount = getValue("nine_by_seven_right_side");
    var tenwidthamount = getValue("ten_by_eight_right_side");
    var framewidth = getValue("framewidth");
    var totaldoorwidth;
    var totaldooramount;
    var framewidthtotaldoorwidth;
    var framespace;

    totaldoorwidth = eightwidth * eightwidthamount
                   + ninewidth * ninewidthamount
                   + tenwidth * tenwidthamount;

    totaldooramount = parseInt(eightwidthamount, 10)
                    + parseInt(ninewidthamount, 10)
                    + parseInt(tenwidthamount, 10);

    framewidthtotaldoorwidth = framewidth - totaldoorwidth;

    framespace = totaldooramount + 1;

    if (framewidthtotaldoorwidth < framespace) {
        alert("You have to many doors on the right side");
    } else { }
}
```

here is a link to my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/steven27030/M52Hf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/M52Hf/84/

you could use the data attribute and be sure to pass in the current element as a parameter on your doorsrightsideFunction call:

```
<select id="framewidth" onchange="doorsrightsideFunction(this)">

 var previousValue = currentelement.getAttribute("data-prev");
    if(previousValue == null)
        previousValue = currentelement[0].value;
```

Comment: I got a downvote for my solution? Does it not do what the OP asked for?

Comment: @user3303279: I understand that. Someone downvoted my answer. I'm not talking about you selecting it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the previous value so you can switch back when necessary, and update the previous value after a successful change.  I would use arrays in various places.

```
var prevValue = Array();
function doorsrightsideFunction() {
    function getValue(idElement) {
        return document.getElementById(idElement).value;
    }
    function setValue(idElement,val) {
        return document.getElementById(idElement).value = val;
    }

    var ids = Array("eight_by_seven_right_side","nine_by_seven_right_side","ten_by_eight_right_side");
    var widths = Array(
        getValue("eight_by_seven_width_right_side"),
        getValue("nine_by_seven_width_right_side"),
        getValue("ten_by_eight_width_right_side")
    );
    var values = Array();
    for(i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
        if (!prevValue[i]) { prevValue[i]=0; }
        values[i] = getValue(ids[i]);
    }    
    var framewidth = getValue("framewidth");
    var totaldoorwidth = 0;
    var totaldooramount = 0;
    var framewidthtotaldoorwidth;
    var framespace;

    for(i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
        totaldoorwidth += values[i] * widths[i];
        totaldooramount += parseInt(values[i], 10);
    }

    framewidthtotaldoorwidth = framewidth - totaldoorwidth;

    framespace = totaldooramount + 1;

    if (framewidthtotaldoorwidth < framespace) {
        alert("You have to many doors on the right side");
        for(i=0;i<ids.length;i++) { setValue(ids[i],prevValue[i]); }
    } else {
        prevValue = values;
    }
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M52Hf/87/)

---

Edit:  In answer to your follow on question in the comment:

> is there a way to make it loop through and find the next size down that would work if they choose to many?

---

Yes, you can have it iterate the values to find one that fits, as long as the initial values are valid (in this case no doors is a perfect initial value).  This also means you don't need to worry about storing any previous value.

I had some fun with this a took some liberties with your code.

First, a few changes in the HTMl:

- for each element with an onChange, have it pass the element that was changed so we can tell which one to modify:
  `<select ... onchange="doorsrightsideFunction(this)">`
- change the IDs of the `_width` and `_height` hidden inputs so they are of the form `<id of select element>_width` (i.e. the width element for the select with `id="eight_by_seven_right_side"` should be `"eight_by_seven_right_side_width"` so you just need to take `id + "_width"` to find it)
- wrap all of the door select elements in a `<div id="doorchoices"> ... </div>` so they can be found programmatically.  This way adding a new door to the system is as simple as adding the select and height/width hidden inputs within the containing div, and the javascript finds and uses them automagically.

The javascript changes, I tried to comment inline:

```
//make ids and widths global to this page so we only have to construct it on page load
var ids;
var widths;

function getValue(idElement) {
    var el = document.getElementById(idElement);
    if (el) {
        return parseInt(el.value);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function setValue(idElement, val) {
    return document.getElementById(idElement).value = val;
}

window.onload = function () {
    //construct id list from elements within the containing div when the page loads
    ids = Array("framewidth");
    widths = Array(null);
    var container = document.getElementById("doorchoices");
    var selections = container.getElementsByTagName("select");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
        ids.push(selections[i].id);
        // get each door's width from the _width element that matches the id
        widths.push(getValue(selections[i].id + "_width"));
    }
}

// el is the 'this' passed from the select that changed
function doorsrightsideFunction(el) {

    console.log(widths);
    console.log(ids);

    var changedIndex = ids.indexOf(el.id);
    //get all of the option elements of the changed select
    var possibleValueEls = el.getElementsByTagName("option");
    var values = Array();
    var possibleValues = Array();
    var framewidth;
    var curValue;
    var totaldoorwidth;
    var totaldooramount;
    var framewidthtotaldoorwidth;
    var framespace;
    var i;


    function calcWidth() {
        totaldoorwidth = 0;
        totaldooramount = 0;
        var i;
        framewidth = values[0];
        //start with 1 since index 0 is the frame width
        for (i = 1; i < ids.length; i++) {
            console.log(i + ")" + ids[i] + " " + values[i] + "(" + widths[i] + ")");
            totaldoorwidth += values[i] * widths[i];
            totaldooramount += parseInt(values[i], 10);
        }
        framewidthtotaldoorwidth = framewidth - totaldoorwidth;
        framespace = totaldooramount + 1;
    }

    // get all possible values from the option elements for the select that was changed    
    for (i = 0; i < possibleValueEls.length; i++) {
        possibleValues.push(parseInt(possibleValueEls[i].value));
    }
    // values should be increasing in order
    possibleValues.sort();
    // except framewidth should be decreasing
    if (el.id == "framewidth") {
        possibleValues = possibleValues.reverse()
    };

    // get the value of each element
    for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        values[i] = getValue(ids[i]);
        if (changedIndex == i) {
            curValue = values[i]
        };
    }

    calcWidth();
    console.log(framewidthtotaldoorwidth);
    console.log(framespace);
    if (framewidthtotaldoorwidth < framespace) {
        alert("You have to many doors on the right side");
        // start with the current value and try each until it fits
        for (validx = possibleValues.indexOf(curValue); validx >= 0, framewidthtotaldoorwidth < framespace; validx--) {
            //change the value in the values array
            values[changedIndex] = possibleValues[validx];
            //change the select to match
            setValue(el.id, possibleValues[validx]);
            //see if it fits
            calcWidth();
        }
    }
}
```

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M52Hf/89/)

and the simplicity of adding another door size - just add this to the HTML:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="twelve_by_ten_right_side_width" id="twelve_by_ten_right_side_width" value="12" />
    <input type="hidden" name="twelve_by_ten_right_side_height" id="twelve_by_ten_right_side_height" value="10" />
    <br />
    <label for="twelve_by_ten_right_side">12x10:</label>
    <select id="twelve_by_ten_right_side" onchange="doorsrightsideFunction(this)">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
```

[New door fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M52Hf/90/)

Comment: nevermind i got it to work in jsfiddle after i changed it to in the head instead of on load.

Comment: is there a way to make it loop through and find the next size down that would work if they choose to many? like if they choose 4 but 3 or 2 would work of that type of door on the chosen length?  The more i look at your answer the more i like it. just wish i understood arrays enough to figure how to use it in more functions i have.

Comment: that worked perfect. it will take me a week to understand the code but it will be worth it when i do.

Comment: is there an easy way to make it handle values that are decimals like 2.5 for windows or walk in doors?

Comment: you gonna hate me for this question but what if you wanted to confirm the selection and instead increase the width to the size that would fit for the number of doors selected.

Comment: As long as the width is a drop-down select, you will be limited to discrete values for the width.  If you make the framewidth element a text entry and validate that it only contains numbers, you could replace the for loop after the alert with `setValue("framewidth",totaldoorwidth + totaldooramount + 1);`

Comment: for decimals, the simplest method is multiply all values by 10, like '<option value="25">2.5</option>` so you can still use parseInt

Comment: joe i wish i could just hire you to do this program lol. it would be alot simplier on me